# UV unwrap - Material cuts in correspondence to edges

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I UV unwrapped the mesh by marking two seams. One for the side of the "cylinder" and one for the base. I applied the quixel material and scaled it down as it was way too big. For some reason the texture shows hard cuts corresponding to some of the edges (which aren't seams because the only seam I marked is on the camera side).  What am I doing wrong?

Addition: I now added more geometry to the cylinder by ctrl + r and scrolling. It has more geometry but those "cuts" are still there.

[image]

[image]

[image]